# Pandas Conditional Shift Based On Another Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple dataframe of people and value. I want to add a column which returns the users next value. This is simple to do with a `shift(-1)`, but I would like the new column to be a null value if the person changes. I could iterate over the rows but that seems like a slow option.

Original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 1], ['A', 4],
                        ['B', 1], ['B', 4]], 
                  columns=['person', 'val'])

    person  val
0   A       1
1   A       4
2   B       1
3   B       4
```

Desired Output:

```
    person  val conditional shift
0   A       1   4.0
1   A       4   NaN
2   B       1   6.0
3   B       6   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['conditional shift'] = df.groupby('person').val.shift(-1)
```

---

```
print(df)

  person  val  conditional shift
0      A    1                4.0
1      A    4                NaN
2      B    1                6.0
3      B    6                NaN
```